# Extract data from*.vtu file

Tags: python, pycharm, vtk

I am trying to extract some data arrays from a *.vtu file

```
import numpy
import vtk.vtk

from vtk import vtkUnstructuredGridReader
from vtk.util import numpy_support as VN

reader = vtkUnstructuredGridReader()
reader.SetFileName("heterogeneousbox-00041.vtu")
reader.ReadAllVectorsOn()
reader.ReadAllScalarsOn()
reader.Update()

data = reader.GetOutput()
GasSaturation = data.GetPointData().GetScalars("Sn")

print(type(GasSaturation))
```

but I get this error: *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vtk'*
PS: I am using pycharm and python3.8 as interpreter!

Thanks in advance

Comment: first, it should be `import vtk` and not `vtk.vtk`.  If still not found, how do you install vtk ?

Comment: Yes import vtk is what I do. I tried: pip install vtk but it doesn't work. I get the following error: ERROR: No matching distribution found for vtk

Comment: So you should rewrite your entire post: it is not a problem about `Extract data ...` but about `Install VTK python`.

Comment: Also which version of python is used by pip ?